# "Transformers: The Last Knight" Unicron horn locations error

Tags: movie, transformers-live-action-series

I have watched the Transformers: Last Knight (2017) movie. It is the fifth film in the live-action film series "Transformers". In the movie, I have noticed that the locations of the emerging horns of Unicron indicated contradictory to each other in various scenes where references to the sites are made. For example, in one scene two camouflaged Blackhawks can be seen with a large Unicron horn in the background with the location indicated on screen as Jordan. But then Jordan is not marked as a horn location in the Maps shown in other scenes.

The map in the study of the Simmons in Cuba shows different locations than the map he later sends to Lord Folgan by himself. No areas in Jordan, South America, Alaska or Bangladesh are indicated in the map sent to Folgan. These locations seem to been replaced by some other locations. Namibia, California and Siberia seem to be the only consistent locations. Furthermore, on the map in the Simmons study, there are seven locations indicated by arrows, but he can be seen saying there are "

> six horns, six locations

" looking at the map.

I have searched if those are listed as errors in online fan pages and have not found any mention.

Here are timestamps that locations are mentioned or shown in maps:

00:07:44.685

00:37:04.633

00:37:41.268

01:24:58.884

Can those be errors in the movie? Or are there some plot facts that make these locations consistent or valid that I didn't catch or understand?

Comment: [Cross-posted from Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/120467/46980).